Thinnest possible vase mode
I'm trying to print a dissolving PVA surface in vase mode using Prusa slicer 2.8.1. Does anyone know if there's a way of making the surface thinner, ideally as thin as possible?
I've read several other similar questions, but they all seem to be focussed on making the wall thicker, not thinner.

Ah - I think I've found it - "external perimeter extrusion width". I will give it a try and see if it works.

If you tried this please post an answer, answering should not be done in comments. Have you tried a smaller nozzle? e.g. 0.2 mm or 0.1 mm
